# secure chmod of php, html, css, js, png, folders?

Tags: linux, security, web, chmod

I have a localhost with files all 777 permission. but if i want to upload them on a real server, what is their correct secure permission for each file type:

php, html, css, js, png and directories

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In server mostly recommended that directories permissions should 755 and files 644. In permissions 777 are not recommended due to security reasons.

Comment: all files 744? how about php?

Comment: All files 644 not 744 due to security reasons, even also for php it will 644. I'm not only guessing our websites are running with these permissions, but for any script it it should 755 or exectable permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are running Apache and it's executing as an unprivileged user, the web server needs to be able to read and serve up your content.

For directories, Apache needs both read and execute. HTML, JS, CSS, and image files only need read permissions. Executable scripts such as PHP require both read and execute to function as intended. So for directories and PHP scripts, you'd want to use `o+rx` or in octal possibly `755` depending on how you want group ownership set. And for non-executable content such as HTML, JS, CSS, and image files, you'd use `o+r` or `744` in octal.

The octal number is a series of bitflags for `owner`, `group` and `other`, respectively. `1` corresponds to `execute`, `2` corresponds to `write` and `4` corresponds to `read`.

To determine what the flag is, you add up each of the bits for each group. So `755` means the owner has full permissions `(1+2+4)` and the group and other have `read` and `execute` permissions `(1+4)`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `644` for `o+r` for non-executable content?